# Second PSU shuts down by itself under load

Tags: power-supply, crossfire

i have 2 PSU one 650watt to hold my i7-2600k 2hdd's and 1(out of 2) r9 290,the second PSU is 340watt and has only my second r9 290.When i load a game then the second psu shuts down and i get a bsod 0x00000116.

Also i tried to swich the second psu to a 300watt psu but i had the same resaults.What i shoud do now?

My setup:

Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-P67X-UD3-B3

CPU: Intel i7-2600k @ 4.2GHz(no turbo boost)

HDD1: WD 1TB

HDD2: WD 2TB

GPU: 2*Sapphire R9 290

Comment: It sounds like you are not providing enough power to the GPU.

Comment: `Radeon R9 290 4GB 512-Bit GDDR5: System Requirements: 750W (minimum)`

Comment: video card only draws power from 12V line, 300W is combined power of all rails and some psu do not like to have no load on other lines